# Sufficient conditions for exchangeability of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

I have a question on the meaning of exchangeable random variables.

Suppose we have a group of $N$ individuals and let $\epsilon_{ij}$ denotes the preference of individual $i$ for being friend with individual $j$ with $i=1,...,N$, $j=1,...,N$ and  $i\neq j$.

Suppose we have an $N(N-1)\times 1$ random vector $\epsilon$ that collects $\epsilon_{ij}$ for $i=1,...,N$, $j=1,...,N$ with $i\neq j$.

(*) Assume $\{\epsilon_{ij}\}$ are exchangeable across $ij$, which means that the probability distribution of $\epsilon$ is invariant to permutations of the labels assigned to individuals.

**Question**: under which sufficient conditions (*) holds?

---

My attempt:

(1) If $\epsilon_{ij}=\alpha_i+\xi_{ij}$ with $\{\alpha_i\}$ i.i.d. across $i$, $\{\xi_{ij}\}$ i.i.d. across $ij$, and $\xi_{ij}$ independent of $\alpha_i$, then (*) holds.

(2) If $\epsilon_{ij}=\alpha_j+\xi_{ij}$ with $\{\alpha_j\}$ i.i.d. across $j$, $\{\xi_{ij}\}$ i.i.d. across $ij$, and $\xi_{ij}$ independent of $\alpha_j$, then (*) holds.

(3) If $\epsilon_{ij}=\alpha_i+\beta_j+\xi_{ij}$ with $\{\alpha_i\}$ i.i.d. across $i$, $\{\beta_j\}$ i.i.d. across $j$, $\{\xi_{ij}\}$ i.i.d. across $ij$, and $\alpha_i, \beta_j, \xi_{ij}$ independent of each other,    then (*) holds.

(4) If $\{\epsilon_{ij}\}$ are i.i.d. across $ij$, then (*) holds

Correct?

Comment: Why condition (1)? It is doubtful that (1) could ensure that $(\epsilon_{11},\epsilon_{12})$ is distributed like $(\epsilon_{11},\epsilon_{22})$, which is necessary for exchangeability.

Comment: Notice that $i\neq j$ so $\epsilon_{11}, \epsilon_{22}$ are not considered. Suppose $N=2$. Let a permutation of labels $\varphi$ be such that $\varphi(1)=2$ and $\varphi(2)=1$. Exchangeability requires (assume we are in a discrete world for simplicity), $P(\epsilon_{12}=a, \epsilon_{21}=b)=P(\epsilon_{\varphi(1)\varphi(2)}=a, \epsilon_{\varphi(2)\varphi(1)}=b)= P(\epsilon_{21}=a, \epsilon_{12}=b)$. Correct?

Comment: @Did I have edited some errors in my question. Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: Can someone explain what it means to "have an $N(N-1)\times 1$ random vector $\epsilon$ that collects $\epsilon_{ij}$..."?. Sorry, this is not my field.

Comment: @pseudoeuclidean I think it only means that $\varepsilon$ is a vector containing all $\varepsilon_{i,j}$, i.e $\varepsilon = (\varepsilon_{1,2},\ldots,\varepsilon_{N,N-1})$ (with $N(N-1)$ entries in total).